# Predicting/Correcting full text search

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, search, laravel-4

I am working on a web application which has a full text search feature working without any problems. I would like to improve this and add a prediction/correction feature to it, meaning that if the user makes a typo or something which has 0 results, a *corrected* version of that input would get queried instead which has results. Basically somethig like Google's `did you mean: x` feature.

Is there an easy built-in way in Laravel to do this, or anything useful to check? I have been Googleing the problem for some time now, but didn't find anything relevant.

I'm using Laravel 4.2 with a MySQL database, if that matters something.

Comment: Something like this - https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/?

Comment: What you're looking for is Fuzzy Logic. This is concerned with approximation matching instead of exact matching. Different algorithms allow you to specify the %age difference to match against. Elastic Search, and Amazon services both have implementations of this but you'll need to research more into it as a precise answer isn't really possible for this type of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the similar case, I used [elastic search](https://www.elastic.co/) for

> Did you mean ...?

Elastic search does a lot more than this like it will sort relevant results on many different cases and many more.
You can use [Elasticquent](https://github.com/adamfairholm/Elasticquent) for Laravel which implements elasticsearch to eloquent.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything built in. Initially I would look at integrating a spellcheck - there are a couple of packages available on packagist, although I don't know how well they perform

https://packagist.org/search/?q=spell

On a second level I guess you could store search terms in the DB and then do "People who searched for x also searched for y"